# Normalize transformed rectangles with photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

Let's say I have some transformed rectangles like the ones here (fig 3,4,6,8):
[image]

Is there a simple way to click on the 4 corners of the rectangle and make the whole image adjust so that the lines are parallel to the image borders?

I can use Photoshop CS 5.1 here, images are very high quality and should stay it.

Answer (score 1):

you just use free transform and put the corners where you want. use guides to make a proper rectangle and the free transform will snap to them when you move it near.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to un-transform other than undo or the History panel.